# can I use master libpq in production

Tags: go, production, libpq

Is it ok to use the master branch of lib/pq in production?
When you execute go get gitlab.com/lib/pq you get the master branch, but there is a release v1.0.0.
Would it be better to use releases instead of master branch?

Comment: It is preferable to use specific version

Answer (score 1):

> [`lib/pq`](https://github.com/lib/pq)
>
> Releases
>
> [v1.0.0](https://github.com/lib/pq/releases)
>
> Initial tagged release. No major recent changes.
>
> [Merge pull request #778 from lib/go-mod](https://github.com/lib/pq/commit/4ded0e9383f75c197b3a2aaa6d590ac52df6fd79)
>
> add a go.mod file in preparation for a tagged release

---

`lib/pq` v1.0.0 adds support for Go versioned modules.

For Go1.12, consider upgrading your production code for Go versioned modules.

The first beta release of Go 1.12  is scheduled for this week (Dec, 3, 2018).

---

> [Go 1.11 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11)
>
> [Modules, package versioning, and dependency management](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#modules)
>
> Go 1.11 adds preliminary support for a new concept called “modules,”
>   an alternative to GOPATH with integrated support for versioning and
>   package distribution. Using modules, developers are no longer confined
>   to working inside GOPATH, version dependency information is explicit
>   yet lightweight, and builds are more reliable and reproducible.
>
> Module support is considered experimental. Details are likely to
>   change in response to feedback from Go 1.11 users, and we have more
>   tools planned. Although the details of module support may change,
>   projects that convert to modules using Go 1.11 will continue to work
>   with Go 1.12 and later. If you encounter bugs using modules, please
>   file issues so we can fix them. For more information, see the go
>   command documentation.

[Proposal: Versioned Go Modules](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/24301-versioned-go.md)

[Go 1.11 Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).